# Why does this answer equal to $(x-x^2)^8$?

Tags: integration

The question derives from page 240 of the Essential Calculus book.

$$\int_5^x (t-t^2)^8\,dt.$$

Finding the derivative is done by using fundamental theorem of calculus. Yes if we can just use that then it should be $(x-x^2)^8$. However, I still don't get this.

According to the wikipedia, it explains the fundamental theorem of calculus as:

Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function defined on a closed interval $[a, b].$ Let $F$ be the function defined, for all $x$ in $[a, b],$ by

$$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\,dt.$$

Then, $F$ is uniformly continuous on $[a, b],$ differentiable on the open interval $(a, b),$ and

$$F'(x) = f(x) \text{ for all } x \in (a,b).$$

In the question above, the $a$ value is specified but we don't have $b$ value. In other words, the interval has not been defined. How can we still apply it? Furthermore, x is not even defined it can be any real number hence $(-\infty,\infty)$ since $a$ is 5 in this case, it can be $4,$ $8$ or $1000000.$ Given the absence of $b$ how can we apply the fundamental theorem of calculus? what if $x$ is less than $5$? say $-1$ or $-2$?

Comment: There are two parts to the FTC. Part 1 generally calls for the upper limit of integration to be a variable, thus making the definite integral into a function of x, which we can talk about differentiating.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs so are you saying we can designate any value of x?

Comment: Yes, your function $F(x)$ is a function of $x$, and it has different values depending which $x$ you plug in. For example, if you plug in $x=a$, we obtain that $F(a)=0$. Do you see why?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs yes since a to a is 0 no area. I was just wondering since the defintion sort of mandates $a \leq x \leq b$ so I just wanted to be very strict regarding the defintion. so if b is absent x can be any value. even less than a (like -5 in this case)

Comment: The only restriction on $x$ is that the domain of $f$ has to include some interval containing both $a$ and $x$. Otherwise, the definite integral from $a$ to $x$ wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Thank you very much sir that $b$ endpoint of an interval just confused me.